# Custom Transition (Animation) between two Activities Android

Tags: android, animation, transition, flip

I have an activity with 4 views inside. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aRpU.jpg).
I want to make an animation that when i click one of the 4 views (e.g. the upper right view) it will zoom in, covering the whole screen, then it will flip and go to the next activity..does anyone know how can i make it and give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

You have to design transition in style.xml

```
<style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
  <!-- enable window content transitions -->
  <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>

  <!-- specify enter and exit transitions -->
  <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/explode</item>
  <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/explode</item>

  <!-- specify shared element transitions -->
  <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">
    @transition/change_image_transform</item>
  <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">
    @transition/change_image_transform</item>
</style>
```

Then call the same in code using `Window.requestFeature()` method.

```
// inside your activity (if you did not enable transitions in your theme)
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);

// set an exit transition
getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
```

Read the below document to get an idea
https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions